# fully passwordless nfs through kerberos

Tags: linux, security, nas, nfs, kerberos

I have a small network that includes a NAS. on which I provisioned, with some effort, a Kerberos server. The Kerberos server allows Linux hosts on the network to create secure NFS mounts. Service keys created on the KDC are distributed to appropriate hosts, and mounts are configured with Kerberos security. Insecure mounts are blocked by the policy configured on the NAS.

Inconveniently, users may access files on the mounts only if they have active tickets on the host from the KDC. This requirement is restrictive, due to inconvenience, and even more so by limiting access to the mounts by automated tasks running with  regular user permissions.

In the early days of NFS, files on a remote volume would appear as local, beginning at boot, and continuously for the entire system session. Security and identity management are important benefits of Kerberos  in NFS, but requiring     users to be  granted tickets is often unnecessary. Since the key distribution and the controlled access to the hosts prevents unwanted access to the NFS mounts, I have no need of user tickets.

Ideally, I would like   users to access  mounts that have Kerberos security without requesting a ticket from the KDC, or even needing a principal registered on it. Any user would have access at all times to any file, provided access would not be restricted by   per-file permissions.

How close to this target scenario is possible through existing tools?

Comment: In that case, do you actually gain any benefits by using Kerberos instead of, say, IPsec? (You do lose performance compared to IPsec.) Are you using Kerberos authentication for any other services or is it literally just NFS?

Comment: @user1686: IPsec knows nothing about the file permissions on the volume. It would be no help to my scenario.

Comment: But NFS still does – by including the user's UID in every RPC request. That's literally how things worked "in the early days of NFS" before Kerberos: the client said "user 1003 is performing this operation", the server trusted that claim and applied permission checks accordingly.

Comment: The objective is to check permissions against the active user on the host with the mount. A ticket from the KDC is not necessary. The symbolic identifier of the user is sufficient.

Comment: Exactly, and that's what you get with the UID-based `sec=sys`, without needing Kerberos in any way.

Comment: I don't want UID-based mappings, nor do I want anyone controlling a node on the network to have full access to all files. I also don't want snooping.

Comment: But if you allow your nodes to specify a "symbolic identifier of the user", even with Kerberos, then you _literally allow_ anyone controlling a node on the network to get full access to all files. Whether with sec=sys or your imagined Kerberos-based host-level authentication, someone controlling a node with this privilege can `su` to any user and get the same result. Avoiding that is precisely the purpose of per-user Kerberos tickets.

Comment: No, access to the NFS volume requires a key from the KDC. Only by controlling the KDC may someone create a mount on his own node.

Comment: You get the same with IPsec, when access to the NFS service requires a host certificate from the local CA. Only by controlling the CA may someone establish an SA for port 2049.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the current NFS Kerberos authentication mechanism (RPCSEC_GSS) does not support this. The principal that's making the call is the one who gets access. So if you don't want users to *manually* get tickets, then you'll need to have the host automatically get tickets *for* them.

In the future, the newer RPCSEC_GSSv3 protocol might have options for allowing hosts to impersonate arbitrary users, but it hasn't yet been finished nor implemented.

---

If you want to allow hosts to impersonate any UID, then you don't need Kerberos at all – switch back to the `sec=sys` security mode that was used "in the old days". In this mode, the host literally gets to specify a symbolic identifier of the user. (Permission checks still happen, of course.)

In the end, there is no functional difference between allowing a host to impersonate any user via Kerberos (authenticated using the host's /etc/krb5.keytab), versus allowing a host to impersonate any user via basic UID claim (authenticated using the host's IPsec or WireGuard private key or) – and the latter will give you much higher performance than GSSAPI can achieve.

---

Within Kerberos, when using existing tools only (without outright implementing some kind of host-level authentication for RPC), the closest thing you have is **constrained delegation with protocol transition** (S4U2Self + S4U2Proxy), where a service is allowed to get tickets to specific other services in the name of a user. It is commonly used in Active Directory environments but is also supported by MIT Kerberos KDCs (and *probably* Heimdal KDCs – the code is there, thanks to Samba, but I do not know how to enable it on Heimdal).

To enable this in a MIT Kerberos KDC you will need to use the LDAP backend; the file-based HDB backend doesn't support storing the additional fields.

1. Set the `ok_to_auth_as_delegate` principal flag on the client's host principal (can be done through kadmin, or by ORing `0x200000` into the `krbTicketFlags` LDAP attribute).

   ```
   kadmin.local modprinc +ok_to_auth_as_delegate host/foo.example.com
   ```
2. Set the client principal's `krbAllowedToDelegateTo` LDAP attribute to a list of NFS service principals that it may create the fake tickets for. (One service per value.)

   ```
   ldapmodify <<EOF
   dn: krbPrincipalName=host/foo.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM,cn=EXAMPLE.COM,ou=Kerberos,o=Example
   add: krbAllowedToDelegateTo
   krbAllowedToDelegateTo: nfs/fs1.example.com
   -
   EOF
   ```
3. Test whether S4U features work, as root:

   ```
   # Acquire host credentials using system keytab
   host_cc=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_host
   kinit -c $host_cc -k
   klist -c $host_cc

   # Acquire NFS tickets on behalf of the user using S4U2Proxy
   kvno -c $host_cc -I $user_name -P nfs/fs1.example.com
   klist -c $host_cc

   # Do the same, but put the tickets in that user's cache
   # so that rpc.gssd would be able to find them
   user_cc=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u $user)
   kvno -c $host_cc -I $user -P nfs/fs1.example.com --out-cache $user_cc
   chown $user: $user_cc
   ```
4. Install *gss-proxy* on the client, and edit its included `nfs-client.conf` to use S4U2Proxy instead of individual client keytabs:

   ```
   [service/nfs-client]
     mechs = krb5
     cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
     cred_store = ccache:FILE:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
     impersonate = yes
     allow_any_uid = yes
     trusted = yes
     euid = 0
   ```

   This example is based on https://github.com/gssapi/gssproxy/blob/main/docs/NFS.md#user-impersonation-via-constrained-delegation.
5. Configure the client's *rpc.gssd* daemon to use gss-proxy by adding `GSS_USE_PROXY=1` to the environment:

   ```
   # systemctl edit rpc-gssd

   [Service]
   Environment=GSS_USE_PROXY=1

   # systemctl restart rpc-gssd
   ```

---

If Kerberos is used exclusively for NFS, and if each host only needs a limited set of users, then the host can store *client keytabs* (which hold the password-derived keys) for those users. This is roughly equivalent to storing the users' passwords, as the keytab allows

Comment: So the KDC will issue tickets even without user credentials, but requesting tickets (through `kinit`) is still necessary?

Comment: Yes, S4U2Proxy allows the host (or some other service) to get user tickets without any user credentials – for an approved set of destination services. It is pretty much meant for this situation. But in the end NFS's RPCSEC_GSS needs a user ticket, therefore _something_ has to get a user ticket for the client's rpc.gssd (it doesn't know how to do S4U2Proxy on its own), although it might not necessarily be `kinit` – it seems the `gss-proxy` daemon has support for this as well.

Comment: (This does have the advantage that it generalizes to SMB/CIFS or any other protocols you might want to provide, instead of being an inherently NFS-specific trick.)

Comment: It would be great if the ticket request could be triggered simply by the user accessing the files, as detected by `gssd`.

Comment: The PAM script has the problem of depending on manual login. Automation is not possible in the general case.

Comment: Citations to  manuals, tutorials,   reference,  or any other sources, if available, would be very helpful.

Comment: In that case, configure rpc.gssd to use gss-proxy and try your luck with the 'impersonate' option of the latter. Gss-proxy already comes with an "NFS client" configuration, although aimed at client-keytab usage.

Comment: I've edited the post with links to gss-proxy docs.

Comment: I'll try this solution as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the LDAP backend?

Comment: Currently not with MIT Krb5, no, because the DB2 backend doesn't implement storage of this additional information. (The reason the LDAP backend supports this might be that FreeIPA needed it.) On the other hand, it may be possible with Heimdal as the KDC, though then I'm not sure about interoperability (I think older Heimdal releases did it differently from AD/MIT/Heimdal-git).

Comment: Though with MIT Krb5, you don't need to keep _user accounts_ in LDAP, or otherwise configure clients to speak LDAP at all – only the KDC database needs to be stored there.

Comment: A limitation is I have deployed [MIT Kerberos in a container](https://github.com/gcavalcante8808/docker-krb5-server) that  includes no support for the LDAP backend. I could run a separate container for the LDAP server, or integrate with the main instance on site, but the solution still would depends on considerable additional components and complexity inside the container running the KDC and administrative server.